# Can anyone help me with this circuit analysis problem?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

The problem I have is that my answer depends on the assumption of the direction of I<sub>1</sub>. If I assume the direction of I<sub>1</sub> to be like in the picture, I got I<sub>1</sub> = 0.00005A and I<sub>2</sub> = 0.00205A. The equations I set up is as follows:

- I<sub>1</sub> + 40I<sub>1</sub> = I<sub>2</sub>
- 3 - (29.5 × 10<sup>3</sup>)I<sub>1</sub> - 0.5 - 500I<sub>2</sub> = 0

However, if I assume the direction of I<sub>1</sub> to go in the opposite direction, I expected to get -0.00005A for I<sub>1</sub>, but that's not the case. I got I<sub>1</sub> = -0.00025A and I<sub>2</sub> = -0.00975A.

The new system of equations is as follows:

- 40I<sub>1</sub> = I<sub>1</sub> + I<sub>2</sub>
- 3 + (29.5 × 10<sup>3</sup>)I<sub>1</sub> - 0.5 - 500I<sub>2</sub> = 0

So, which one is the correct answer?

Comment: `can anyone help me?` is not a question about a problem ... please update your title

Comment: Well, first off you have a dependent source that says 40*I1 and has its own direction. If you change the direction of I1 as defined elsewhere in the schematic without changing your dependent source definition, then you've changed the circuit and should expect a different result. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Well, is a dependent current source allowed to change direction? That's my confusion. My understanding is that it doesn't matter which way you assume a current to go, the math will tell you at the end. If it is possitive, then your inital assumption was correct. If it's negative, then your assumption was wrong, and the current is actually going the other way. But regardless, the magnitude is still the same.

Comment: I didn't get -0.00005A for I1 when I assumed I1 to go in the opposite direction. That's my confusion

Comment: Before I write much more, I want you to just think about something for a moment. Suppose I1 were to somehow increase (more positively) just a little bit. (We don't need a reason, let's just say it does happen for some reason.) Then the 40*I1 source would also increase (more positively.) Together, these currents could be forced to combine at their joint node above the 500 Ohm resistor and must move through that 500 Ohm resistor. So the voltage across it would have to increase.

Comment: But if you changed I1's direction without changing the 40*I1 source's direction, then if I1 were to somehow increase (same unknown reason for now), then the 40*I1 source would also increase, but in this case the I1 current would subtract away from the shared node above the 500 Ohm resistor. In other words, the slight positive change in the 40*I1 source would enter the node, but since I1 points the other way it would subtract from that, so that only 39*i1 would go through the 500 Ohm resistor. In short, it's just not the same thing.

Comment: You can also solve that circuit very simply. The voltage across the 500 Ohm resistor is (40+1)*I1*500 and the voltage across the 29.5k resistor is I1*29.5k. So the following must be the case: \$\left(40+1\right)\cdot I_1\cdot 500\:\Omega+I_1\cdot 29.5\:\text{k}\Omega=3.0\:\text{V}-0.5\:\text{V}\$. Or, in short, \$I_1=50\:\mu\text{A}\$. It just falls out. But if you changed the direction of I1 then \$\left(40-1\right)\cdot I_1\cdot 500\:\Omega-I_1\cdot 29.5\:\text{k}\Omega=3.0\:\text{V}-0.5\:\text{V}\$ which gets quite a different value.

Comment: You know what. I get it now. Both solutions are valid. It just depends on which direction you want I1 to go in the circuit